# Migrating to TypeScript. Why is my function not recognised?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I am trying to migrate a working JavaScript project to TypeScript.
The project uses nightwatch.js

This is my main test class:

```
declare function require(path: string): any;

import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import signinPage = require("../built/pages/signinPage.js");
import instancesPage = require("../built/pages/instancesPage.js");
dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
    'User can sign in'(client) {

        console.log("Sign in as email: " + process.env.EMAIL);

        signinPage
            //   .navigate()
            .signin(process.env.EMAIL, process.env.PASSWORD);

        // give it time to load

        client.pause(5000);

        instancesPage.expect.element('@homepageWelcomeTitle').text.to.contain('Welcome to the CJDocs Home!');

        client.end();
    }
}
```

This is the pageObject, containing the offending function:

```
  module.exports = {  
  signin: function(email, password) {
    return this
      .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
      .setValue('@emailInput', email)
      .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
      .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
      .click('@signinButton')
  },
  elements: {
    emailInput: {
      selector: 'input[type=email]'
    },
    passwordInput: {
      selector: 'input[name=password]'
    },
    signinButton: {
      selector: 'button[type=submit]'
    }
  }
};
```

When I run this (running from terminal using NPM test), I get an error:

```
TypeError: signinPage.signin is not a function
```

As far as I can see, signinPage.signin IS a function.

Why is it not recognizing my function?

Comment: @str False, it is the correct syntax for importing modules. It's TS-specific. But the OP should export with `export = {...}`

Comment: @BackSlash. converting to export = {...} did not make it work.

Comment: @SteveStaple Try doing exactly as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

Comment: Not really an answer but does adding a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) fix your problem: `const signin = signinPage.signin as (...args: any[]) => any;`

Comment: @BackSlash - Followed you link (Try doing exactly as described here). Can't see anything remotely similar to what I am doing.

Comment: If you do `console.log(signinPage)` after the import, what do you see?  But even if you get past this roadblock, I don't expect the code to work because nothing is establishing a `this` context for the `signin` function that provides `waitForElementVisible`, etc.  I believe you're supposed to go through the `client.page` mechanism described in the "Working with Page Objects" section of the [documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/).

Comment: @Matt McCutcheon - the documentation does not help with Typescript.

Comment: Looks like this question is being superseded by https://stackoverflow.com/q/52669219 .

Answer (score -1):

this code is still very much JS/ES5 and not so much TS. 
Try to change `import signinPage` into `import * as signinPage`. Maybe that helps.

But really I recommend looking up ES6 / TS functionalities like classes.
So make signinPage.ts:

```
export default class signinPage {
  signin(email, password) {
    return this
      .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
      .setValue('@emailInput', email)
      .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
      .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
      .click('@signinButton')
  }
  get elements() {
    return {
      emailInput: {
        selector: 'input[type=email]'
      },
      passwordInput: {
        selector: 'input[name=password]'
      },
      signinButton: {
        selector: 'button[type=submit]'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then change your import to `import singinPage from "../src/pages/signinPage"`

so you're pointing from TS file to another TS file, but you dont need the .ts extention.

Comment: I tried this approach. Just to make matters more complicated, got a new error: [ts] Property 'waitForElementVisible' does not exist on type 'signinPage'.

Comment: import * as importPage was flagged as illegal syntax. 'from' expected.

Comment: (Flion) - I tried moving away from export default. Your code will not work. It has illegal syntax: Property 'waitForElementVisible' does not exist on type 'signinPage'. Also, import * as importPage was flagged as illegal syntax. 'from' expected.