# Typescript: function is not a function in JavaScript to Typescript conversion?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to convert an existing, working JavaScript project to TypeScript, & I specifically want to use the PageObject pattern.

I getting this error when I run npm test: TypeError: client.page.signinPage is not a function.

This is where I call it:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

module.exports = {
'User can sign in'(client: any) {
    const signinPage = client.page.signinPage();
```

My function is here:

```
const signinCommands = {  
  signin(email: String, password: String) {
    return this
      .waitForElementVisible('@emailInput')
      .setValue('@emailInput', email)
      .setValue('@passwordInput', password)
      .waitForElementVisible('@signinButton')
      .click('@signinButton')
  }
};

module.exports = {  
  url: 'https://cjdocs.herokuapp.com/auth/signin',
  commands: [signinCommands],
  elements: {
    emailInput: {
      selector: 'input[type=email]'
    },
    passwordInput: {
      selector: 'input[name=password]'
    },
    signinButton: {
      selector: 'button[type=submit]'
    }
  }
};
```

My page_object_path is set in the nightwatch.json file.

So, how come it does not think my function is a function?

The whole project can be downloaded from: https://github.com/hellfireSteve/nightwatch-typescript-pageobject

Comment: `signinPage` is a class which you instantiate by using the `new` keyword. Then you have an object of said class on which you can call functions on. Please look up a typescript tutorial as this is quite the basic stuff...

Comment: By the way... classes should start with an upper case letter.

Comment: @Wernerson I am doing a TypeScript course right now.

Comment: @Wernerson changing it to const loginPage = new client.page.signinPage(); made no difference. Error still says: loginPage.signin is not a function.

Comment: Instead of running the tests, since you're using TypeScript, look at the errors TypeScript gives you.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha - don't know what you are talking about. The errors are shown when I run npm test. There are no compile errors.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] when asking questions to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @SteveStaple what is `client.page.signinPage`? Because it's not your `signinPage` class... If you want to create a new instance you'd write `new signinPage()`.

Comment: @SteveStaple out of interest, which course are you following?

Comment: @DavidWalschots https://www.udemy.com/understanding-typescript/learn/v4/

Comment: As I said on [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52298128), I think the problem is that you're not correctly following the "Working with Page Objects" instructions in the [documentation](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/).  What is the file structure of your project?  Have you set the `page_objects_path` option?  We can try to help you troubleshoot, but we may not be able to solve the problem unless you do the work to put together a reproducible example that doesn't rely on your company network.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I have read the documentation. Half of the code I have used actually comes from that page!

Comment: @AndyJ have now provided an example of my project at https://github.com/hellfireSteve/nightwatch-typescript-pageobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the `client.page.signinPage is not a function` error.  When I change the `page_objects_path` from `pages` to `built/pages` (because I presume Nightwatch is looking for JavaScript files and not TypeScript files), that error goes away and I get a different error, which I believe is because I don't have the browser driver installed correctly.  Try changing the `page_objects_path` and hopefully your tests will work.